# Someone know the name of that animation?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, pixel-bender

I dont even know the name which I should google it, I tried genie effect, but it`s not actually a genie effect! If someone has an link how to do this in flex,flash, pixel bender, will help a lot as well, or just the name of the animation will help too.

[image: animation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it has a different name when it's animated, but what you show in the "before" picture is [Pincushion Distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29#Radial_distortion).

Comment: thanks for replay.so do u know some algorithm?! or somewhere I can find something closer?! I `m trying to implement that animation in flex. so I `m really far!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this effect with the [ft-Cubic Lens Distortion](http://aescripts.com/ft-cubic-lens-distortion/) filter. Hat tip to Mark Ransom. Sorry I couldn't figure out how to reply to his post.